# HTML Table that spans two columns

Tags: html

I have a very simple HTML table with some text, and want a link to span two of the table columns, but to still keep the two columns separate for the purpose of formatting. I've tried something like

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <a href="#">
            <td>text 1</td>
            <td>text 2</td>
        </a>
    </tr>
</table>
```

but the link doesn't appear and when inspecting the HTML, the `<a>` tag isn't there at all. Is there any way to do this? I ***don't*** want the text inside to span two columns, just the link to work on the text and the space in between.

Comment: Illegal HMTL..... Use two `A` tags or an onclick of the table row `<tr onclick="location='otherpage.html'" style="cursor:pointer">`

Comment: It's not possible. What's the larger goal here? What are you trying to accomplish with that type of layout?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is not a valid HTML. You cannot have `<tr> -> <a> -> <td>`

Try some thing like below -

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tr onclick="location='#'" style="cursor:pointer; color: blue;">
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid blue;">text 1</td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid blue;">text 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

- Added `border-collapse: collapse;` on table tag to remove space between the columns
- `onclick="location='#'"` on tr tag to redirect to the new page (behaviour of anchor tag)
- `color: blue;` on the tr tag to make it look like anchor tag
- `border-bottom: 1px solid blue;` on the td tags so that there is an underline like the anchor tag

You can see this on [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-2iztvf).

Answer (score 0):

The anchor spanning two cells is illegal HTML

Instead use two A tags

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="...">text 1</a></td>
    <td><a href="...">text 2</a></td>
  </tr> 
</table>
```

or an onclick of the table row

```
<tr onclick="location='otherpage.html'" style="cursor:pointer">
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an Anchor tag to span two columns is wrong
Instead collapse the two table columns

Answer (score 0):

You can't put an anchor tag  in a table.. it's wrong.

Rather..  put the  tag in the  tag then set the span to 2.. to cover two columns.. Or u cab just do  tag in the  twice.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A single anchor tag  should not be used for two elements.
Rather, use something like
 text 1
 text 2

Comment: Welcome to SO, please answer the question with some codes too.